# Script/tool to delete specified filename

Tags: file, powershell, batch-file

I need a batch file /script/tool to delete specified files in folder.
I have a folder with a lot of .xml files. It can contain files named difference of only a few characters (indicating the date).

```
aa_bb_000000001_2015_9_1.xml
aa_bb_000000001_2015_9_15.xml
aa_bb_000000001_2015_10_1.xml

aa_bb_000000002_2015_5_5.xml
aa_bb_000000002_2015_8_14.xml
aa_bb_000000002_2015_10_1.xml

aa_bb_000000005_2015_7_7.xml
.
.
```

The length of this part is 15 string

```
aa_bb_000000001
```

This part represents a date

```
2015_10_1
```

I need to delete all the files that part of the name with a date is earliest.
As a result batch should stay only files:

> aa_bb_000000001_2015_10_1.xml
>
> aa_bb_000000002_2015_10_1.xml
>
> aa_bb_000000005_2015_7_7.xml
>
> .
>
> .

Comment: You should post what you have so far and then people can help you making it work. Don't expect community people to do the work for you....

Comment: I don't understand this `I need to delete all the files that part of the name with a date is earliest.` and the result. It doesn't matched.

Comment: @dark fang From those files aa_bb_000000001_2015_9_1.xml
, aa_bb_000000001_2015_9_15.xml, aa_bb_000000001_2015_10_1.xml that should be deleted aa_bb_000000001_2015_9_1.xml
, aa_bb_000000001_2015_9_15.xml because have earlier date in filename (2015_9_1 and 2015_9_15).

Comment: Well, you should give it a try by yourself. If you have any problems, edit the question and let us know. You can't just ask a question without providing your script, and let us do all of it from scratch for you!

Comment: @ dark fang I know but I don't have conception how to start with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution that's fairly short. To understand how the code works, it would be best to focus on what the Group-Object command does, what regular expressions are, and how they interact with the -match operator:

```
$Groups = Get-ChildItem "C:\XMLFiles\*.xml" | Group-Object {$_.Name.Substring(0, 15)}
$FilesToKeep = @{}
foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $MaxDate = "00000000"
    foreach ($FileInfo in $Group.Group) {
        $FileInfo.name -match "(\d{4})_(\d{1,2})_(\d{1,2}).xml$" | Out-Null
        $Date = $Matches[1]+([int]$Matches[2]).ToString("00")+([int]$Matches[3]).ToString("00")
        if ($Date -gt $MaxDate) {
            $MaxDate = $Date
            $FilesToKeep[$Group.Name] = $FileInfo.FullName
        }
    }
}
Get-ChildItem "C:\XMLFiles\*.xml" | Where-Object {-not $FilesToKeep.ContainsValue($_.FullName)} | Remove-Item
```

Comment: The script works as it should. I'll try to analyse to understand how it works. Thank you very much for your work and your time of his writing !